# Search for Flashbuilder 4.6 64 bit

Tags: apache-flex

Anyone know a link where i can get Flash Builder 4.6 64 bit version. It seems Adobe has taken it off their page and the only version i can come across is the 32 bit version. Help

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased a copy of Flash Builder 4.6 64-bit you should contact Adobe directly and tell them you need 4.6 for compatibility reasons. Even then they might want you to upgrade to 4.7.

Im not even sure there was a 64bit release. Are you positive thats what you need? If you had a trial or hacked version, your likely out of luck.

Comment: No..i just need a trial version. I can only download a 32 bit, and my laptop is a 64 bit....I have 4.7, but the design view has been dropped. so i need a 4.6 because of design view